# Is there a way to add an attribute to only 1 row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Take this table as an example :

```
CREATE TABLE UserServices (
    ID BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Service1 TEXT,
    Service2 TEXT,
    .
    .
    . 
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Every user will have different number of services, so lets say the table starts with 10 columns for services for each user. If one user will have 11 services, must all other users have 11 columns also? Now of course it is a table and row needs to have the same number of columns, but it is just seems like an awful waste of memory. Maybe the use of another database type is better?

Thank you!!

Comment: Remove all the `serviceN` columns and add one `service` column to store the `text` and another column to store the service number problem solved

Comment: with mysql, answer is no. Maybe you should take a look at mongoDB or something similar

Comment: The relational database way to do this is add a Services table. You then reposition UserServices as a joining table between users and services - it just contains a UserID and ServiceID. Then you can have as many services for each user as you like, and will be able to easily determine users who share the same services.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a boatload of nulls isn't really a "waste of memory" because the space is negligible - hard disks cost pence per gigabyte, programmers cost tens/hundreds of $/hr so it's certainly economical to burn the space and it's not really a great argument for avoidance.

There is a better argument though, as others have said; databases don't do variable numbers of columns for a particular ID in a table, but they DO do variable numbers of rows per ID.. This is how DBs are designed: columns are fixed, rows are variable. Everything that a database does and offers in terms of querying, storage, retrieval, internal design etc is optimised towards this pattern

There are well established operations (called pivots) that will turn your vertical arrangement of data into horizontal (with nulls) at query time, so you don't have to store the data horizontally

Here's a pivot example:

```
Table:
ID, ServiceIdentifier, ServiceOwner
1, SV1, John
1, SV2, Sarah
2, SV1, Phil
2, SV2, John
2, SV3, Joe
3, SV2, Mark

SELECT
  ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ServiceIdentifier = 'SV1' THEN ServiceOwner END) as SV1_Owner,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ServiceIdentifier = 'SV2' THEN ServiceOwner END) as SV2_Owner,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ServiceIdentifier = 'SV3' THEN ServiceOwner END) as SV3_Owner
FROM
  Table
GROUP BY
  ID


Result:
ID SV1_Owner SV2_Owner SV3_Owner
1  John      Sarah
2  Phil      John      Joe
3            Mark
```

As noted, it's not a huge cost to just store the data horizontally and if you're sure the table will never change/ not need new columns adding on a weekly basis to cope with new services etc, then it might be a sensible developer optimisation to just have columns full of nulls. If you'll add columns regularly, or one day have thousands of services, then vertical storage is going to have to be the way it goes

Comment: That said, it's still a daft way to store data.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little on what's already been said:

> Is there a way to add an attribute to only 1 row in SQL?

No, and that's kinda fundamental to how relationship databases (SQL) work - and that's in any version of SQL, whether it's mysql, t-sql, etc.  If you have a table - and you want to add an attribute to that table, it's going to be another column, and that column will be there for every row.  Not just relational databases - that's just how tables work.

But, that's not how anyone would do it.  What you would do is what Alan suggested - a separate table for Services, then a 3rd table (he suggested naming it 'UserServices') that links the two.  And that's not a one-off suggestion - that's pretty much "the" way to do it.  There's no waste.

> Maybe the use of another database type is better?

Possibly, if you want something with less restrictions, then you could go with something other than SQL.  Since SQL is so dominant, everything is usually categorized as NOSQL. - Mongo is the most popular NOSQL database currently, which is why RC brought it up.